# Syntax error for assigning variable in python

Tags: python, tkinter, syntax, pygame

I started to make this new python project on tic tac toe, but when I try to run it, there is an error with the "=" in `winScreen = Tk()`

```
import pygame
from pygame import *
from tkinter import *
import time
import random

#functions
def main():
    def PVP_and_destroy():
        display.destroy()
        PVP()

    def AI_and_destroy():
        display.destroy()
        AI()

    def multiplayer_and_destroy():
        display.destroy()
        multiplayer()
        
    display = Tk()
    
    display.title("MENU")
    display.geometry("300x300")
    display.config(bg="black")

    Label(display, text = "Welcome to TIC TAC TOE", fg = "white", bg = "blue", font = (15)).pack()
    Button(display, text = "PvP", width = 15, command = PVP_and_destroy).pack(pady = 35)
    Button(display, text = "A.I.", width = 15, command = AI_and_destroy).pack()
    Button(display, text = "Multiplayer", width = 15, command = multiplayer_and_destroy).pack(pady = 35)
    Button(display, text = "EXIT", width = 15, command = exit).pack()
    
    display.mainloop()

def grid(win):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for i in range(2):
        x += 150
        y += 150
        pygame.draw.line(win, (255,255,255), (x,0), (x,450))#draws vertical lines
        pygame.draw.line(win, (255,255,255), (0,y), (450,y))#draws horizontal lines

def playerTurn(posX, posY, turn, square, win, font):
    #looking at the first square
    if posX == 0 and posY == 0 and square[0][0] == 1:
        if turn%2 == 0:
            text = font.render("X", True, (255,0,0), (0,0,0))
            textRect = text.get_rect()
            textRect.center = (75,75)
            win.blit(text, textRect)
            square[0][0] = "X"
        else:
            text = font.render("O", True, (255,0,0), (0,0,0))
            textRect = text.get_rect()
            textRect.center = (75,75)
            win.blit(text, textRect)
            square[0][0] = "O"
    #looking at the second square
    if posX == 1 and posY == 0 and square[1][0] == 2:
        if turn%2 == 0:
            text = font.render("X", True, (255,0,0), (0,0,0))
            textRect = text.get_rect()
            textRect.center = (225,75)
            win.blit(text, textRect)
            square[1][0] = "X"
        else:
            text = font.render("O", True, (255,0,0), (0,0,0))
            textRect = text.get_rect()
            textRect.center = (225,75)
            win.blit(text, textRect)
            square[1][0] = "O"
    #looking at the third square
    if posX == 2 and posY == 0 and square[2][0] == 3:
        if turn%2 == 0:
            text = font.render("X", True, (255,0,0), (0,0,0))
            textRect = text.get_rect()
            textRect.center = (375,75)
            win.blit(text, textRect)
            square[2][0] = "X"
        else:
            text = font.render("O", True, (255,0,0), (0,0,0))
            textRect = text.get_rect()
            textRect.center = (375,75)
            win.blit(text, textRect)
            square[2][0] = "O"

    #looking at the fourth square
    if posX == 0 and posY == 1 and square[0][1] == 4:
        if turn%2 == 0:
            text = font.render("X", True, (255,0,0), (0,0,0))
            textRect = text.get_rect()
            textRect.center = (75,225)
            win.blit(text, textRect)
            square[0][1] = "X"
        else:
            text = font.render("O", True, (255,0,0), (0,0,0))
            textRect = text.get_rect()
            textRect.center = (75,225)
            win.blit(text, textRect)
            square[0][1] = "O"
    #looking at the fifth square
    if posX == 1 and posY == 1 and square[1][1] == 5:
        if turn%2 == 0:
            text = font.render("X", True, (255,0,0), (0,0,0))
            textRect = text.get_rect()
            textRect.center = (225,225)
            win.blit(text, textRect)
            square[1][1] = "X"
        else:
            text = font.render("O", True, (255,0,0), (0,0,0))
            textRect = text.get_rect()
            textRect.center = (225,225)
            win.blit(text, textRect)
            square[1][1] = "O"
    #looking at the sixth square
    if posX == 2 and posY == 1 and square[2][1] == 6:
        if turn%2 == 0:
            text = font.render("X", True, (255,0,0), (0,0,0))
            textRect = text.get_rect()
            textRect.center = (375,225)
            win.blit(text, textRect)
            square[2][1] = "X"
        else:
            text = font.render("O", True, (255,0,0), (0,0,0))
            textRect = text.get_rect()
            textRect.center = (375,225)
            win.blit(text, textRect)
            square[2][1] = "O"

    #looking at the seventh square
    if posX == 0 and posY == 2 and square[0][2] == 7:
        if turn%2 == 0:
            text = font.render("X", True, (255,0,0), (0,0,0))
            textRect = text.get_rect()
            textRect.center = (75,375)
            win.blit(text, textRect)
            square[0][2] = "X"
        else:
            text = font.render("O", True, (255,0,0), (0,0,0))
            textRect = text.get_rect()
            textRect.center = (75,375)
            win.blit(text, textRect)
            square[0][2] = "O"
    #looking at the eigth square
    if posX == 1 and posY == 2 and square[1][2] == 8:
        if turn%2 == 0:
            text = font.render("X", True, (255,0,0), (0,0,0))
            textRect = text.get_rect()
            textRect.center = (225,375)
            win.blit(text, textRect)
            square[1][2] = "X"
        else:
            text = font.render("O", True, (255,0,0), (0,0,0))
            textRect = text.get_rect()
            textRect.center = (225,375)
            win.blit(text, textRect)
            square[1][2] = "O"
    #looking at the last square
    if posX == 2 and posY == 2 and square[2][2] == 9:
        if turn%2 == 0:
            text = font.render("X", True, (255,0,0), (0,0,0))
            textRect = text.get_rect()
            textRect.center = (375,375)
            win.blit(text, textRect)
            square[2][2] = "X"
        else:
            text = font.render("O", True, (255,0,0), (0,0,0))
            textRect = text.get_rect()
            textRect.center = (375,375)
            win.blit(text, textRect)
            square[2][2] = "O"
    pygame.display.update()

        ###win screen##############
    def yes():
        pygame.quit()
        winScreen.destroy()
        PVP()

    def no():
        pygame.quit()
        winScreen.destroy()
        main()
           
    if square[0][0] == square[1][0] and square[1][0] == square[2][0] or square[0][1] == square[1][1] and square[1][1] == square[2][1] or square[0][2]== square[1][2] and square[1][2] == square[2][2] or square[0][0] == square[0][1] and square[0][1] == square[0][2] or square[1][0] == square[1][1] and square[1[1] == square[1][2] or square[2][0] == square[2][1] and square[2][1] == square[2][2] or square[0][0] == square[1][1] and square[1][1] == square[2][2] or square[2][0] == square[1][1] and square[1][1] == square[0][2]:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        winScreen = Tk()
        winScreen.geometry("350x100")
        winScreen.title("Winner!")
        running = False
            
        winner = None
        if turn%2 == 0:
            winner = "X"
        else:
            winner = "O"
        Label(winScreen, text = winner + "'s the WINNER!\nDo you want to play again?", font=(5)).grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        Button(winScreen, text = "Yes", width = 10, command = yes).grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        Button(winScreen, text = "No", width = 10, command = no).grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        Button(winScreen, text = "EXIT", width = 10, command = exit).grid(row = 1, column = 2)
                    
        winScreen.mainloop()

def PVP():        
    screen = (450,450)
    pygame.init()
    font = pygame.font.Font("C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial.ttf",150)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    win = pygame.display.set_mode(screen)#creates display
    title = pygame.display.set_caption("GAME")
    update = pygame.display.update()
    running = True
    square = [[1,2,3],
              [4,5,6],
              [7,8,9]]
    turn = 1
    
    while running:
        clock.tick(10)
        grid(win)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:#checks if the cross is being clicked
                        running = False
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:#sees if any button from the mouse is pressed
                    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    #simplifying which box the mouse clicks
                    posX = pos[0]//150
                    posY = pos[1]//150
                    playerTurn(posX, posY, turn, square, win, font)
                    turn += 1
                    
                    
        pygame.display.update()#updates the display
    pygame.quit()#closes the window
def AI():
    pass

def multiplayer():
    pass
main()
```

I have spent like half an hour trying to edit, understand and solve the problem, which I have yet not found a solution for.

P.S. please do not complete my project, I want to finish this project on my own.

Comment: ```square[1[1] == square[1][2]``` Heres your error. Above  ``` winscreen=Tk()```  line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error in the longest line: you didn't close a square bracket.

[image: screenshot]

In the screenshot (Wrapped after each `OR` for clarity) I highlighted the error.

So, the longest line should be:

```
if square[0][0] == square[1][0] and square[1][0] == square[2][0] or square[0][1] == square[1][1] and square[1][1] == square[2][1] or square[0][2] == square[1][2] and square[1][2] == square[2][2] or square[0][0] == square[0][1] and square[0][1] == square[0][2] or square[1][0] == square[1][1] and square[1][1] == square[1][2] or square[2][0] == square[2][1] and square[2][1] == square[2][2] or square[0][0] == square[1][1] and square[1][1] == square[2][2] or square[2][0] == square[1][1] and square[1][1] == square[0][2]:
```